# Draft Watermark with Beamer

Tags: beamer, draftwatermark

Is is possible to use `\usepackage{draftwatermark}` with beamer? I tried it, and the watermark does not show on the slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}

\author{Test}
\title{Sample document for the draftwatermark package}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Test}
test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm curious why would you show slides with a draft watermark.

Comment: "UNOFFICIAL", actually. I needed to share some slides with some preliminary results, but I needed to make it clear that they were not officially endorsed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should make the canvas transparent:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}%transparent canvas
\author{Test}
\title{Sample document for the draftwatermark package}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Test}
test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```